# Typescript concat string to string if he is avaialble

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some values like this

```
let originalString = 'original'

let text1 = 'string1';
let text2 = 'string2';
```

I need to concat those text values in **originalString**, and final string should look like this

```
let originalString = 'original/string1/string2';
```

The problem I have is that sometimes one of the text string can be null, and then it has to remove from originalString, here is example with null

**When second is null**

```
let originalString = 'original'

let text1 = 'string1';
let text2 = null;

let originalString = 'original/string1';
```

**When is null**

```
let originalString = 'original'

let text1 = 'null';
let text2 = 'null';

let originalString = 'original';
```

And so on, maybe sometimes even all can be null, or two of them, anyway I need to add them in new string

Comment: Show us how you concat them. Either check if variable is null before concat or after concat remove `//` from string and `/` from the end of string

Comment: `originalString = [originalString, text1, text2].filter(str => str !== null && str !== 'null').join('/')`  should do the work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push all of them into an array, and then your final array can be like this

```
const stringArray = ["original", null, "string2"]
```

Finally, you can use a filter to get NOT null values and then join them all

```
originalString = stringArray.filter(x => x).join("/")
```

In your example, you're also using a `'null'` string for values. You can add that value into your filter too.

```
originalString = stringArray.filter(x => x && x !== 'null').join("/")
```